# Pyspark Dataframe Merge Rows by eliminating null values

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null

i have a Pyspark Data Frame like this one

```
+-----------+-------+----------+-------+-------+---------+
| ID_PRODUCT| VALUE | TIMESTAMP| SPEED |  CODE | FIRMWARE|
+-----------+-------+----------+-------+-------+---------+
|          3|      1|      null| 124,21|   null|     null|
|          5|      2|      null| 124,23|   null|     null|
|          5|      2|      null| 124,26|   null|     null|
|          6|      4|      null| 124,24|   null|     null|
|          3|      1|      null|   null|   6764|     null|
|          5|      2|      null|   null|   6772|     null|
|          5|      2|      null|   null|   6782|     null|
|          6|      4|      null|   null|   6932|     null|
|          3|      1|      null|   null|   null|        1|
|          5|      2|      null|   null|   null|        1|
|          5|      2|      null|   null|   null|        1|
|          6|      4|      null|   null|   null|        1|
|          3|      1|  17:18:04|   null|   null|     null|
|          5|      2|  18:22:40|   null|   null|     null|
|          5|      2|  18:25:29|   null|   null|     null|
|          6|      4|  18:32:18|   null|   null|     null|
+-----------+-------+----------+-------+-------+---------+
```

and i want to merge the columns of it, it should look like (for example):

```
+-----------+-------+----------+-------+-------+---------+
| ID_PRODUCT| VALUE | TIMESTAMP| SPEED |  CODE | FIRMWARE|
+-----------+-------+----------+-------+-------+---------+
|          3|      1|  17:18:04| 124,21|   6764|        1|
|          5|      2|  18:22:40| 124,23|   6772|        1|
|          5|      2|  18:25:29| 124,26|   6782|        1|
|          6|      4|  18:32:18| 124,24|   6932|        1|
+-----------+-------+----------+-------+-------+---------+
```

I tried to use:

```
df = df.groupBy('id').agg(*[f.first(x,ignorenulls=True) for x in df.columns])
```

however, this is just giving me just the first value of the column and i need all the records. Because to one ID i have different registered Timestamps and different registered values, which im now loosing.

Thanks for the advice

Comment: how does it know which row to merge with which?why is it merging the rows with id 2 and 6?

Comment: This is an example, the otiginal one does it with Timestamp

Comment: please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question, which includes all necessary details to solve your problem.

Comment: @mck i did an update on it :)

Comment: how does it know which row correspond to which, if there are multiple combinations of ('id_product', 'value'), e.g. for (5, 2)?

Comment: That´s why it doesn´t work, the only difference is the Timestamp

Comment: It's a question for you, not for the code. Which rows do **you** want? You need to specify the rules, before you write the code. **How** do you want to create your resulting dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but essentially you can do a collect_list for each id and column, and explode all resulting lists. In this way, you can have multiple entries per id.

```
from functools import reduce
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = reduce(
    lambda x, y: x.withColumn(y, F.explode_outer(y)),
    df.columns[2:], 
    df.groupBy('id_product', 'value').agg(*[F.collect_list(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns[2:]])
).distinct()
```